# Bash Script from MATLAB

Tags: bash, matlab, docker

I have a bash script that I want to execute from within MATLAB. I use system() to execute it. However when it executes I get

```
docker: command not found
```

I am using docker commands from within the script and I have it properly installed in my computer. If I run the script from the terminal using the exact same command I have running from the system() call in MATLAB it works fine. To the extent that if I just remove the bash script execution call from my MATLAB function (the last line) and run the function and then run the script from the terminal it all works.

For example here is a MATLAB function:

```matlab
function foo(container_id)
% Copies this file to the root of a docker container given by container_id
system(['./copy_foo.sh ' container_id])
end
```

And here is the bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

docker cp foo.m $1:/root
```

Running it from the terminal

```
./copy_foo.sh CONTAINER_ID
```

produces the desired result. Running the Matlab function from the command window

```
foo('CONTAINER_ID')
```

yields:

```
docker: command not found
```

Comment: Could you share a minimal reproduction example for the script in question?

Comment: And also show how you are using the `system` command

Comment: The shell run by `system` might use a different `PATH`, see "UNIX tips and limitations" [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html)

Comment: I edited the question with what you asked. How could I set the path to make this work?

Comment: I had a similar issue a couple of years ago and could not find a solution for it at the time. Should have asked this on SO though! The way that I got around it eventually was by calling Matlab from a script. Basically, I rearranged and broke the `foo` function so that all calls to Matlab and others, including my system commands, are executed from a Linux environment. This is not a legitimate solution to your question and is probably an ugly workaround anyway but I just wanted to share my experience.This may be particularly difficult to implement if your `system` command is in a loop.

Comment: Yeah I think that is a little too hacky for my purposes. Thanks anyways though!

Comment: the `docker` executable does not seem to be within your $PATH in the subshell that Matlab opens when you use their `system()` call. What if you explicitly _set_ the same PATH (that you have in your bash terminal) in your bash script?

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB changes the environment variables when starting up. In particular, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `PATH` are affected. There are two solutions:

1. Use explicit path to the `docker` executable. Your Bash script would contain the line `/path/to/docker cp foo.m $1:/root`.
2. Ensure the environment is initialized properly before running your script. Your MATLAB script would contain the line `system(['bash --login -c ./copy_foo.sh ' container_id])` (or something similar, I haven't tested this...).